# Python Flask CORS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: python, ajax, api, flask, flask-cors

I have a simple Ajax script written on a Shopify Product Page.  This script would be triggered and send a json message to the API server whenever the upload button is clicked

```
 jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://e20e2287e2cb.ngrok.io/return_json",
            type: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            success: function (result) {
              var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( result );
                jQuery(".select-loader").remove(); 
                jQuery("body").removeClass('active-loader');
                jQuery("#upload_image").removeClass("err");
                jQuery("#upload_image").val("");
                jQuery("#google_folder_id").val(obj.imguniquename);
                jQuery("#customImage").val(obj.imgname);
                jQuery("#customImageUrl").val(obj.folder_id);
                jQuery("#customUniqueImage").val(obj.imguniquename);
                
                jQuery("#upload_image").after('<p class="note note--success">Image uploaded successfully.</p>');
                Cookies.set('google_folder_id', obj.imguniquename);
                Cookies.set('customImage', obj.imgname);
                Cookies.set('customImageUrl', obj.folder_id);
                Cookies.set('customUniqueImage', obj.imguniquename);

            }
          });
```

In the API server, I have the following code written in Python:

```
#Flask Library
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok

app = Flask(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG
CORS(app)
run_with_ngrok(app) 

@app.route("/return_json", methods=["POST"])
def returnJson():
    return jsonify({'folder_id':'yoyo', 'img':'adad', 'imgname':'bibi', 'imguniquename':'kaka'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**Can anyone tell me why I would have the following errors in the browser console whenever the Ajax script is triggered?**

1. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://e20e2287e2cb.ngrok.io/return_json' from origin 'https://www.abcabc.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
2. POST https://e20e2287e2cb.ngrok.io/return_json net::ERR_FAILED

Meanwhile, on the API server end, the debug log looks fine to me as follow:

**DEBUG:** flask_cors.extension:Request to '/return_json' matches CORS resource '/*'. Using options: {'origins': ['.*'], 'methods': 'DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT', 'allow_headers': ['.*'], 'expose_headers': None, 'supports_credentials': False, 'max_age': None, 'send_wildcard': False, 'automatic_options': True, 'vary_header': True, 'resources': '/*', 'intercept_exceptions': True, 'always_send': True}

**DEBUG:** flask_cors.core:CORS request received with 'Origin' https://www.abcabc.com

**DEBUG:** flask_cors.core:The request's Origin header matches. Sending CORS headers.

**DEBUG:** flask_cors.core:Settings CORS headers: MultiDict([('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://www.abcabc.com'), ('Vary', 'Origin')])
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2021 11:04:44] "POST /return_json HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I haven't noticed you're already using Flask-CORS I'm updating this answer with some further investigations.

I've fired up a testing environment and managed to make this cross-origin request work properly without changing your code. During this process, I came up with the following possible reasons for your issue:

1. Be sure to request an existing tunnel endpoint. Fetching closed NGROK tunnel endpoints result in CORS error, it does not raise a 404. To be sure I'm requesting the correct tunnel I wrote an index view route that just returns success. I also used this endpoint to ensure the CORS was properly set for all HTTP methods (GET, POST...);
2. Be sure to import logging, Flask can lazy evaluate apps and raise exceptions only in request time. Check out your console for tracebacks;
3. In Flask, if an exception occurs during a request, the request handling flow is aborted and Flask-CORS will never be called to add it's headers in the response object, and your browser will always complain about 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. That's why you should always check your browser's 'Response Tab', it may contain a traceback or some other useful information;
4. Check for some info in NGROK introspect accessing http://localhost:4040/, it may help you track many issues;
5. I faced some issues running flask-ngrok provided through pip. I've downloaded its source code from GitHub and imported it into my demo app. Frankly, I would ditch this extension and just run `$ ngrok http 5000` in another console;
6. Be sure to set FLASK_DEBUG=true or it may hide some info/tracebacks from you.

Check this Gist for the source code I've used and some evidence: https://gist.github.com/magnunleno/8dad91f133a22322250d6cb609792597

If you find any new info or traceback, please let me know so we can work out a solution.

### Old Answer

That happens when you run your server under a specific domain (in your case e20e2287e2cb.ngrok.io) but your web client runs in a different domain (suppose [www.abcabc.com](http://www.abcabc.com)) and they try to communicate. You should really take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

This behavior can be configured by managing your app headers `Access-Control-*` and, luckily, there is a nice extension that does that for you called [Flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

Comment: If you look at the code I posted, I already have flask_cors imported and declared by following the instruction from https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.  Also, based on the debug log from the API server, looks likes flask_cors already set the response header with Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Sorry, haven't noticed that you're already using flask-cors. If it is all set up it shouldn't be happening. I'll set up a similar environment to check this, but in the meanwhile have you checked your browser network tab after the request error? What is the raw server response? Is there any traceback from Flask in your shell?

Comment: Hey @BrianLo, just to be clear. In your example code, you're using `logging` but there is no `import logging`. Any chance you forgot to import it? Depending on how Flask is set up, it can ignore this kind of error during startup and only raise this kind of exception during requests, and since the request is aborted the CORS headers are not set. This is a common issue I had to deal with when working with CORS to...

Comment: @MagunLeno **logging** is already imported.  I just didn't post all my code here.  You may find the screen capture of the network tab here: 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/19t6p-_vBbSmmVkPyY6TFKtPg-fiCanJp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey @BrianLo, I've just built a testing environment for your issue and all worked fine. Please check the updates I've made in my original answer.

Comment: You are right.  The code should have no issues.  I deployed my API code to Google App Engine and it works fine.

Comment: have you solved it @BrianLo? What was the exact issue?

Comment: @MagunLeon, I found the problem.  But I am not able to fix it still.

The Error appears whenever there is data attached to the AJAX POST.  In my case, I have  "data: form_data"

But if I leave the data attribute as blank, the CORS error disappears.  Below shows how I define form_data:

form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById('upload_image').files[index]);
form_data.append("api_key", "9Sgf7AGvSRQn72uB2sdfdsu");

Comment: Hey @BrianLo, just tested with form_data and all worked fine (https://imgur.com/a/eb1mBgL). Used the follogin JS: `form_data = new FormData(); form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById("img").files[0]); form_data.append("api_key", "teste-api-key"); jQuery.ajax({ url: 'https://bb4c2b68681b.ngrok.io/return_json', type: 'POST', data: form_data, processData: false, contentType: 'application/json', success: function (result) {console.log(result)} })`. When the error occurs, is there any flask exception? what's in the response content?